# Compiling simplehello world c++ program with v8

Tags: v8

While trying to execute the simple hello world c++ program in V8 in ubuntu using the following command I am getting errors

the command is

```
    g++ -Iv8/include hello_world.cpp -o hello_world.o

v8/out/native/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a 

v8/out/native/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_snapshot.a -lpthread
```

the error is

```
g++: error: v8/out/native/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a: No such file or directory

g++: error: v8/out/native/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_snapshot.a: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you installed g++?

Comment: I've deleted my answer because the errors you are getting are dependent on your v8 installation and where they are relative to your project.  Make sure that the folders exist relative to your current project directory (you may have to go back or forward some levels in the folder structure first).

Comment: I would be following this https://developers.google.com/v8/build, but if you have specific problems post a separate question and I'll take a look.